# Не получается задать медиа запрос

Tags: css3, html5, media-queries

страница выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но когда размер окна меньше 710px номер телефона должен исчезать и появляться иконка телефона внутри которой ссылка. но почему то иконка не отображается, в инспекторе есть этот блок но его размер 0 на 0.
помогите исправить пожалуйста

```css
.phone a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.phone a:hover {
    color: #1A9F29;
    font-size: 27px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.phoneMediaShow {
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

img.phoneMediaShow {
    width: 40;
}

@media (max-width:710px) {
    .phoneMediaShow {
        display: block;
    }
    .phoneMediaHide {
        display: none;
        z-index: -10;
    }
}
```

```html
                <div class="phone">
                    <a href="tel:+79000000000" class="phoneMediaHide">+70000000000</a>
                    <a href="tel:+79000000000" class="phoneMediaShow"><img src="assets/img/phone.svg"
                            alt="Позвонить нам" class="phoneMediaShow"></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: P.S. первый раз пишу медиа запрос так что строго не судите)

Comment: дело не в медиа-запросе - просто у Вас картинке задан width: 40; а надо 40px

Comment: точно, спасибо.